# How to restrict a programmer to use a dependency in the pom.xml for spring boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependency-management, embedded-jetty, undertow

For example

[Undertow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat)(Spring boot - using Undertow container)

[Jetty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat)(Spring boot - using Jetty container)

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I wanted to restrict a programmer to use undertow or jetty dependency in their code.

Comment: You could use the `enforcer-plugin`, for instance to ban some dependencies, see here: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html

Comment: What od you mean by "restrict to use"? Disallow using equivalent alternatives? Enforce that the dependency's class is used at least once in the project? Require that is't specified explicitly in pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks Tome.. enforcer-plugin works for me.